# Scraping data through paginated table using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping data through google finance's historical page for a stock (http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3ASIEMENS&ei=PLfUVIDTDuSRiQKhwYGQBQ).

I can scrape the 30 rows on the current page. The issue I am facing is that I am unable to scrape through the rest of data in the table (31-241 rows). How do I go to the next page or link.
Following is my code:

```
import urllib2
import xlwt #to write into excel spreadsheet
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Main Coding Section

stock_links = open('stock_link_list.txt', 'r')  #opening text file for reading

#url="https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3ASIEMENS&ei=zHXOVLPnApG2iALxxYCADQ"
for url in stock_links:
    OurFile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    OurHtml = OurFile.read()
    OurFile.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(OurHtml)
#soup1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "gf-table-wrapper sfe-break-bottom-16"}).get_text()
soup1 = soup.find("table", {"class": "gf-table historical_price"}).get_text()

end = url.index('&')
filename = url[47:end]
file = open(filename, 'w')  #opening text file for writing
file.write(soup1)
#file.write(soup1.get_text())   #writing to the text file
file.close()            #closing the text file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to fine tune it and I would catch more specific errors but you can keep increasing the `start` to get the next data:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3ASIEMENS&ei=W8LUVLHnAoOswAOFs4DACg&start={}&num=30"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  requests
# Main Coding Sectio
start = 0
while True:
    try:
        nxt = url.format(start)
        r = requests.get(nxt)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        print(soup.find("table",{"class": "gf-table historical_price"}).get_text())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    start += 30
```

This gets all the table data up to the last  date feb 7 :

```
......

Date
Open
High
Low
Close
Volume

Feb 7, 2014
552.60
557.90
548.25
551.50
119,711
```

Comment: Thank you Padraic C. Your Answer helped me learn something new today. I appended "&start={}" to my existing links list. It worked like a charm. I couldn't upvote your answer as I lack reputation points. The day I have points i'll come here and upvote this awesome answer.

Comment: @NitheshKHP, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at first sight the `Row Limit` option allows to shows maximum 30 row per page but I manually changed query string parameters to greater numbers and realizes we can view max 200 rows per page

Change URL to

`https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3ASIEMENS&ei=OM3UVLFtkLnzBsjIgYAI&start=0&num=200`

It will show 200 rows

And then change `start=200&num=400`

But more logically, if you have many other sunch kind of links.

Then you can scrape the Pagination area, the last TR and grab those links of next pages and scrape

Comment: Thanks Umair. I did play with the url after your suggestion, helped me improve my code.